# How to apply the 'current_page_item' class to an archive page in `wp_list_pages()`?

Tags: functions, wp-query, wp-list-pages

So I have the following custom `wp-query` working on my site:

```
function custom_front_page($wp_query){
    if($wp_query->get('page_id')==get_option('page_on_front')){
        $wp_query->set('post_type','album');
        $wp_query->set('page_id',''); // empty
        // fix conditional functions
        $wp_query->is_page = false;
        $wp_query->is_front_page = true;
        $wp_query->is_archive = true;
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = true;
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_front_page');
```

however, altering the query in this way keeps the page link in my `wp_list_pages()` nav from receiving the `current_page_item` class (it no longer thinks it's a page at all).

How can I get around this?

PS I know I can make a separate link and apply the class conditionally, but is there a way to alter the function above, or the call to `wp_list_pages()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following filter:

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'foo_bar');
function foo_bar($html){
    //Create a regex pattern to identify the LI element with preg_match
    //Create another pattern to identify the class attr and alter it with preg_replace
    return $html;
}
```

As I'm not familiar with the exact elements you are working with, I can't write up a regex for you. In theory, following these steps should work for you.